# C# draw with Alpha channel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a panel on which I draw a radius frame with shadow. But I have a simple frame and a single color. How can I make her to be with smooth tints?

I think you need to use RGB and Alpha channel.

```
   Color BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(161)))), ((int)(((byte)(164)))), ((int)(((byte)(169)))));

    private void AfyTextBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawShadow(e);

    GraphicsPath path = RoundedRectangle.Create(0, 0, this.Width - 5, this.Height - 5, 3);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(BorderColor), path);
}
```

Comment: The casting in line one is excessive and looks horrible. You only need the integer literal.